# Find row whose value is always zero pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple table like -

Table A -

| Seller | Date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | 1-Aug | 0 |
| Jon | 1-Aug | 2 |
| Kon | 1-Aug | 3 |
| Kat | 1-Aug | 2 |
| Mat | 1-Aug | 4 |

Table B -

| Seller | Date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | 2-Aug | 0 |
| Jon | 2-Aug | 2 |
| Kon | 2-Aug | 3 |
| Kat | 2-Aug | 0 |
| Mat | 2-Aug | 4 |

Table C -

| Seller | Date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | 3-Aug | 0 |
| Jon | 3-Aug | 2 |
| Kon | 3-Aug | 3 |
| Kat | 3-Aug | 0 |
| Mat | 3-Aug | 4 |

Table D -

| Seller | Date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ron | 4-Aug | 0 |
| Jon | 4-Aug | 2 |
| Kon | 4-Aug | 3 |
| Kat | 4-Aug | 0 |
| Mat | 4-Aug | 4 |

I need to find the seller list whose value is always zero like -

Ron - Always zero

Another finding is - Find the seller whose value is zero in last 3 dates like -

Kat - Zero in the last 3 dates. In Table A for date 1-Aug Kat had some value.

Create a list of sellers like that. I have many data in similar types of tables.

**Note -**  Tables are not in order by dates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First is necessary create DataFrame with converting columns to datetimes and sorting:

```
L = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

df=pd.concat([x.set_index('Seller')['sales'].rename(x['Date'].iat[0]) for x in L], axis=1)
df.columns = pd.to_datetime('2023'+df.columns, format='%Y%d-%b')

df = df.sort_index(axis=1)
print (df)
        2023-08-01  2023-08-02  2023-08-03  2023-08-04
Seller                                                
Ron              0           0           0           0
Jon              2           2           2           2
Kon              3           3           3           3
Kat              2           0           0           0
Mat              4           4           4           4
```

Then test `0` values and get list of names from indices if all values match:

```
m = df.eq(0)

out1 = df.index[m.all(axis=1)].tolist()
print (out1)
['Ron']
```

And for test only last 3 zero values:

```
N = 3
out2 = df.index[m.iloc[:, -N:].all(axis=1)].difference(out1).tolist()
print (out2)
['Kat']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a list of dataframes:

```
lst = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

# concatenate by Seller
# check if all values are 0
s = (pd.concat([d.set_index(['Seller'])[['Sales']] for d in dfs], axis=1 m)
       .eq(0).all(axis=1)
     )

# get indices of matches
out = s.index[s].to list()
# ['Ron']
```